# Prive Function in JS access to variables

Tags: javascript, private

I have a JS function with the structure of

```
 function myFunc (method){
      this.type = method;
      this.border = '20';
      this.add = function(){
           // some codes
           privateFunc();
      }

      var privateFunc = function(){
           //my private function
      }
  }
```

The problem is, that the private function does not have access to any of the variables (this.type, this.border). They are not defined inside it! Why not?! How can I have a private function there with access to the variables?

Comment: what do you mean they are no defined? whats the error. what are trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness

```
 function myFunc (method){ 
      this.type = method; 
      this.border = '20'; 
      // take a reference to the current object
      var self = this;
      this.add = function(){ 
           // some codes 
           privateFunc(); 
      } 

      var privateFunc = function(){ 

           //now you can access your members via self variable
           self.border = 10;
      } 
  }
```

The clue here is the usage of closure.

Comment: `+1` ahh now this is the thing the OP needs ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The `this` value is different inside `privateFunc` (it will be the global object, not the instance).

The most direct solution is to force the `this` value inside `privateFunc` to the same as in `myFunc` using `.bind`:

```
var privateFunc = function() {
  //my private function
}.bind(this);
```

There are shims for `.bind` available for older browsers.

Comment: An alternative to rebinding `this` would be to rename it in a variable according to the scope you like. I often see lines like `var self = this` in this type of code — when you need to access that scope inside another function, you'd refer to it with `self.type`, etc.

Comment: @Jon: I personally find that a little bit more cluttering; using `.bind` is somewhat more elegant in my opinion. But tastes differ; the `self` way has also been posted.

Comment: @pimvdb Yeah, it's hard to keep up with SO posters :) Rebinding `this` is a little counterintuitive to me, as reading through someone's code at first glance, I'd generally take `this` to always refer to the scope at hand.  Additionally, wouldn't it change the `this` keyword inside `privateFunc`?

Comment: @Jon: "wouldn't it change the `this` keyword inside `privateFunc`" - yes, that's the reason I used it. Instead of the global object, `this` is the instance, and since you never need the global object as `this` it's a bit safer and easier - you can get the instance properties without an extra variable. But I do get your point.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work **fine** for me:

```
function myFunc(method) {
    this.type = method;
    this.border = '20';
    this.add = function() {
        // some codes
        privateFunc();
    }

    var privateFunc = function() {
        alert(this.type);
    }

    privateFunc();
}

myFunc('hello')
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4qnaH/

Comment: I assume the OP uses `new myFunc`; otherwise one is polluting the global scope.

Comment: @pimvdb you know what happens when you **ass** u **me** :-P